# Generate Word Document from Html text

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC 4 system that fill a Word Document according to what the client inserts at the Mail interface.
I've put a TinyMCE textarea to get the content of the mail, and it returns a HTML to my backend.

How can I insert the HTML data in the word document (inside a content control), obeying the format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this library it might be what you are looking for

https://github.com/onizet/html2openxml

Comment: Hey, I think thats it.
But, how can i put that value inside a Content Control?